# Using vanilla + busybox Linux kernel, how to check if partition is encrypted?

Tags: busybox, disk-encryption

I have a networked drive that runs off vanilla Linux Kernel, and ultra-minimalist BusyBox, on a Ralink SoC custom CPU. It has SMB inside, Telnet access, as well as HTTP server. Even basic commands such as *apt* are not installed, adding to the difficulty.

It is sold as a fully-encrypted storage drive, but I would like to verify that fact by myself.

How would I check if the drive inside is really encrypted, without tearing apart the device?

Comment: How do you enter the encryption credentials? Do you get a password prompt at boot time? How?

Comment: There's no password entered at boot time. However, the application that uses it does ask for a password, and a passphrase. I made a quick test with another NAS whose configuration is better known, as the target for this application, and I could see myriads of files coming in, likely all encrypted since they don't trigger any specific type using _file_ and _TrID_. Backup is well below this NAS capability, nerver going above 6MBps on a gigabit LAN.